# IN clause has parameter doesn't work in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have "Name IN (@NameList))" inside of the stored procedure as one of the conditions.

The parameter is declared as `@NameList varchar(100) = ''`

When I execute the procedure with string like EXEC myProc `@NameList='''a'''`
the procedure returns nothing, but when I replaced the parameter with hard coded value like `'a'` it succeeded.

I put a PRINT statement inside the SP and it prints exactly `'a'`

What's wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What's wrong is that the `IN` clause expects a **list of values** to check against, but you're providing only a **single string** as input.

Comment: @marc_s  an IN statement will work with a single value.  Where username in ('ralph') for example works fine.  Not that you should, but you could.

Comment: @marc_s Although I do agree, if Lys was to use this method for a comma separated list it will not work, as the commas would be part of the string which will fail.

Comment: It seems like you're building up towards this point, so I'll offer this advice now. The best way to solve the problem of wanting to pass multiple values to SQL Server is to use a type *designed* for holding multiple values (ideally, table-valued parameters. Less ideally XML or JSON). You're pushing *yourself* into this problem by instead trying to pass multiple values in a *string*.

Answer (score 1):

Please read my comments as well but one solution would be to split your comma separated string into a table and then join onto that:

```
   declare @list varchar(max) = '13,14,15,13,14,15,13'

   SELECT
      LTRIM(RTRIM(a.b.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(255)'))) Parish
   FROM
     (
      SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' +  REPLACE(@list,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) x)t 
      CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')a(b)
```